# "They" or "Them"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, difference, grammaticality-in-context

Why for example in these sentences like that should use them instead of they and what is possible to put in between "want" and "them/they", I mean so or that or something else?

> I want ***them*** not to recognize you.
>
> I want ***they*** not to recognize you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to treat "they" as the subject of the infinitive phrase "not to recognize you".

Under a traditional analysis, infinitives do not have subjects -- ever.  The traditional parts of the sentence are these:

Subject:  I
Verb: want
Direct Object: them
Object Complement:  not to recognize you

Verbs that take both direct objects and object complements are called *complex transitive* verbs.  The object and its complement are two separate constituents, not a single phrase.  As the direct object, "them" takes its objective case form.

Under a more modern analysis, infinitives may have subjects, but those subjects do not take their subjective case forms.

There are many verbs that can take complete subordinate clauses as their objects.  The verb "want" isn't one of those (at least in my dialect), but several similar verbs do.  For example:

> I hope that they don't recognize you.

In such a case, there is no infinitive.  The two different structures cannot be combined.

A sentence like "I want that they not to recognize you" or "I hope that they not to recognize you" looks like pure nonsense.  The word "they" is in its subjective form, and so it wants to attach to a finite verb -- but there is no finite verb available, only an infinitive.

> I want them not to recognize you.

Looking at the original sentence again and using a traditional analysis, "them" is the direct object.  It belongs to the verb "want".  Placing anything between a verb and its object is an interruption.  There is no need for a "so" or "that" or anything else.

This is slightly different than "I hope that they don't recognize you".  In this sentence, the "that" is optional, but it does serve a purpose.  It shows that the entire clause "they don't recognize you" is meant to do the same job that a simple noun or pronoun can do.  Thanks to the "that", we know that "[that] they don't recognize you" doesn't belong in a separate sentence.  The whole clause, including this optional "that", is the direct object.  We still have nothing that separates the object from its verb.

Comment: "He looks like she/her (for example: Mom) looked like dad." - is this sentence correct and is there she not her?

Answer (score 5):

"They" is a *subject pronoun* and, as the name implies, is used as a subject. "Them" is an *object pronoun* and is used as a direct or indirect object.

This is an example of [grammatical cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_case) which are a feature of many Indo-European languages: some sources describe English as having *subjective*, *objective* and *possessive* cases. The impact of these cases is minimal in English as compared to other languages like German, but the distinction between *them* and *they* is one instance.

The more idiomatic way to write your sentence is:

> I don't want them to recognize you.

Comment: @TypelA is there any articles or something like that with similar sentences? I can't find

Comment: @Boyep Sentences similar to / articles about what?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these is correct at all.  The closest thing would be "I do not want them to recognize you."  It would make more sense to say something like, "I hope they won't recognize you," because if you are speaking when you say this, Americans will wonder why you're talking awkwardly, otherwise.